# data transfer from hdfs to hbase using pig

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

when i try to copy data from hdfs to hbase uisng pig with more than two columns( or fields ) in input file. I am getting error.  Detailed example:

file in HDFS: /home/1.txt

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
```

Hbase Table with two column families:    create 'table1','P','S'

Pig commands:

```
A= load '/home/1.txt' using PigStorage('\t') as (one:chararray,two:chararray,three:chararray,four:chararray);

STORE A INTO 'hbase://table1' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('P:one,P:two,S:three,S:four');
```

Error logs:

```
*********
013-09-20 15:42:25,314 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - ERROR: Index: 1, Size: 1
2013-09-20 15:42:25,315 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
2013-09-20 15:42:25,315 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStats - Script Statistics:

HadoopVersion   PigVersion      UserId  StartedAt       FinishedAt      Features
0.20.2-cdh3u6   0.8.1-cdh3u6    hdfs    2013-09-20 15:41:45     2013-09-20 15:42:25     UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_201309051922_0192   A       MAP_ONLY        Message: Job failed! Error - NA hbase://hh2,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/1.txt"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "hbase://hh2"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201309051922_0192


2013-09-20 15:42:25,315 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2013-09-20 15:42:25,352 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Index: 1, Size: 1


*********
```

But when I try copying only two fields it works fine. below code:

```
A= load '/home/1.txt' using PigStorage('\t') as (one:chararray,two:chararray);

STORE A INTO 'hbase://table1' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('P:one,P:two,S:three,S:four');



[s@namenode ~]$ hadoop version
Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u6
Hbase version : Version 0.90.6-cdh3u6
Pig version:  Apache Pig version 0.8.1-cdh3u6 (rexported)
```

Comment: above input file 1.txt is tab separated.

Comment: 1 2 3 4  :::::these are tab separated.

Comment: Try `A= load '/home/1.txt' using PigStorage('\t')` and `DUMP A` to see if there are 4 columns really in the data

Comment: While storing data into hbase, you have to provide rowkey. While storing data using HBaseStorage first element is treated as rowkey. Probably that's why while storing only two elements you don't get an error. To check it, store two columns, and load the same data from HBase using HBaseStorage using -loadKey, and without this parameter.  You will notice the difference in the result. This is just a hint, but I'd go this way...

Answer (score 0):

A = LOAD '/home/1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int, name:chararray, city:chararray);

Comment: Please add more context. And do read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)